# Is it possible to export a dynamic import in a Node module?

Tags: javascript, typescript, create-react-app, rollupjs, dynamic-import

I've written an npm package that calls a dynamic `import()`. It's written in and compiled by TypeScript, for which I've set the compiler option `module: "esnext"` - in other words, the compiled output leaves the `import()` call intact.

Now what I was hoping would happen, was that I could load the module into an application, which would then resolve the call (`import('cross-fetch').then(/* ... */)`) for me.

However, even though I've bootstrapped the application using Create React App (i.e. it's set up to do quite a bit of polyfilling and such already), I'm still getting an error:

> Error: Cannot find module 'cross-fetch'

Is it possible, today, to have a client-side application set up to resolve dynamic imports in one of its dependencies to another Node module? And if so, which bundles can I use, and how should it be configured?

Answer (score 0):

I found out that, yes, this is possible, but the module name should be a static string, rather than an expression. Then at least Webpack will be able to resolve it.